# Getting Data From Button Failed with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to put video play button in my table using below example code.

```
https://codepen.io/JacobLett/pen/xqpEYE
```

I have two PHP files called get-list.php which is providing data for table like below

```
$tempRow['VIDEO_FILE'] = (!empty($row['VIDEO_FILE']))?'

           <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary video-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/A-twOC3W558" data-target="#myModal">
  Play Video 3
</button>':'No Video';
```

and I am displaying that in my index.php like below in table

```
<th data-field="VIDEO_FILE" data-sortable="false">VIDEO</th>
```

JavaScript code is below

```
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function() {

// Gets the video src from the data-src on each button

        var $videoSrc;  
        $('.video-btn').click(function() {
            $videoSrc = $(this).data( "src" );
        });
        console.log($videoSrc);



        // when the modal is opened autoplay it  
        $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {

        // set the video src to autoplay and not to show related video. Youtube related video is like a box of chocolates... you never know what you're gonna get
        $("#video").attr('src',''$videoSrc'' + "?autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0" ); 
        })



        // stop playing the youtube video when I close the modal
        $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
            // a poor man's stop video
            $("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc); 
        }) 






        // document ready  
        });



        </script>
```

Displaying button in table working fine, open modal is working fine but video in modal not showing and I am getting `javascript error like $videoSrc is not defined.`

I am new in javascript and does not getting idea why my button is not passing data to my index.php however button working fine for open modal dialogue. Let me know if someone can give idea.
Thanks!

Comment: Please show me your javascript code.

Comment: @SanatGupta, I have added javascript code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created the $videoSrc variable?

```
var $videoSrc;
```

Comment: Hi!, How I can create it? in example code its not any where. I am following this and https://codepen.io/JacobLett/pen/xqpEYE Thanks!

Comment: Its on the line 5 in javascript tab in that exact codepen. @rajrathod